# How can I query this sort of relationship in Eloquent?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

The schemas go as following:

```
Likes
id (pk)
UserID
FreestyleID    

Freestyle:
id (pk)
BeatId

Beat:
id (pk)
trackId

Track:
id (pk)
GenreId

Genre:
id (pk)
Title
```

Really I would like to get a collection of Freestyles by their genre ID where they have likes. I have tried quite a few things including relationships such as:

```
Genre model:
public function beat()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Beat', 'App\Track', 'GenreId', 'TrackId');
}
```

However, the above will return results like the following because each track can have up to three beats.:
[image: Result]

Let me know if you need to see anything more.

Answer (score 2):

you are on the correct way, but you will need a bit more of code.
First of all, you can change your Genre's function name to beats() - just for convention, because it will return multiple registers :P.
Second, with hasManyThrough you will get all Beats related (through Track) with Genre. 
Then, you can access to the Freestyles related with that Beat:

- Create the relation in your Beat and Freestyle Model:

Beat:

```
public function freestyles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Freestyle');
}
```

FreeStyle:

```
public function beat()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Beat');
}

public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
}
```

- Get the related Freestyles that have Likes with:

> has('freestyles.likes')

So, you can do a function like this (Genre Model):

```
public function beatsWithLikes()
{
    return $this->beats()->has('freestyles.likes');
}
```

I hope It helps you.

Comment: Thank you for this! Am I correct in accessing the beatsWithLikes() method via something like:             

    $genre = Genre::find($request->genre[0])->beatsWithLikes()->with('freestyle.likes')->get();
            dd($genre);

I believe I am almost there now, thanks for the push in the right direction and your tips on naming conventions :D